How to Configure .NET 7 web application to access Azure MySql Flexible Server with managed Identity?
I have a web application with .NET 7 that uses MySQL, I wanna deploy this app to a WebApp on Azure, but before that, I am trying to access the db using Azure managed Identity and not MySql User and Password both from local and from the WebApp without having to change anything.
We can fully access the mysql server using the connection string with user and password but we are tryign to avoid that if possibile.
I am already signed In to VS using my Microsoft Entra Admin, so I can retrieve my Azure token successfully, the problem is I can't find a way to integrate or use it into the connection to the Db, especially after MySqlConnection Class has removed the AccessToken Property.
What I did was:

Create WebApp resource and activate ManagedIdentity.
Create MySQL Flexible server and give the identity created in the webApp permessions to access it.

Anyway, I DID NOT CREATE a mysql user that has the managed Identity ObjectId as a name! should I do that? could that be the problem? but if so, wouldn't that be using userID and Pass again?
This is how I we get the connection string, as you can see the token here is not used:
services.AddDbContext<ContrattoCompliantDbContext>(options =>
        {
            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var token = tokenCredential.GetToken(
                new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })).Token;
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContrattoCompliantDbContext");
            
            options.UseMySQL(connectionString);
        }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

the connection string right now is like this:
"connectionString": "Server=Server-name;Database=dbName;SslMode=Required;SslCa=Certificates/myCert.crt.pem;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=True;PersistSecurityInfo=False;"

Can you point out what's that I am missing here please? there are no clear explanation or what soever on how to use this type of authentication using mysql with EntityFramework core on the microsoft Documents!

Have you seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=mysql-sc%2Cuserassigned-sc%2Cdotnet%2Cdotnet-mysql-mi%2Cdotnet-postgres-mi%2Cwindowsclient  , it shows after it is setup to get an access token and pass that in the connection string.

As @Scott Mildenberger mentioned, to connect to your MySQL database using Azure managed identity, you need to retrieve an access token for the identity and use it as the password when connecting to the database.
Code Snippet:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<Movie>(options =>
{
    var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    var token = tokenCredential.GetToken(
        new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })).Token;
    var connectionString = "Server=mydb.mysql.database.azure.com;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=" + accessToken + ";SslMode=Preferred;";

    options.UseMySQL(connectionString);
}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Using MySqlConnection  class from the  MySql.Data  package to connect to the database. And SSL mode can be Preferred or Required, mostly Preferred mode is recommended for production environments.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity#connecting-using-managed-identity-in-c

and the user name would be the WebApp name? if so, when created, we create it without a password right?

username can be found in the connection string as mentioned in the MSDOC.
